# Error on use of SQL Compact

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-ce

i use VS2010 + Framework3.5 + Sql Compact in Project. But when I use the SQL Compact. display the following warning:

The specified store provider cannot be found in the configuration, or is not valid.

for get my data from SQLCE:

```
EFConn conn = new EFConn(); 
dataGridView1.DataSource = conn.Students.ToList();
```

its ok. but, for send data:

```
EFConn con = new EFConn();
Student objstd = new Student();
objstd.Name = "Sheli";
objstd.Family = "Makro";
con.Students....
```

is no method Sutdents.AddObject

And there is always the following warning:

The specified store provider cannot be found in the configuration, or is not valid.

thanx for help me...

Comment: I download Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5 Service Pack 2 for Windows Desktop and installed it. Error disappeared. But still no method to Sutdents.AddObject(). Please help me...

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the connection string to your application xml.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the platform to x86 instead of Any CPU ?

I had this problem and it seemed to come from x64 provider.

Comment: Shutdown VS2010. Uninstall the SQL compact completely. Reboot. Install the SQL compact completely. Reboot. Restart VS2010.

Comment: I download Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5 Service Pack 2 for Windows Desktop and installed it. Error disappeared. But still no method to Sutdents.AddObject(). Please help me...

Answer (score 0):

```
verify your string connection

    here example

    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="ConsoleApplication1.Properties.Settings.Database1ConnectionString"
            connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\YourDataBase.sdf"
            providerName="Microsoft.SqlServerCe.Client.3.5" />
    </connectionStrings>
    </configuration>

verify your provider

providerName="Microsoft.SqlServerCe.Client.3.5"
```

Comment: error: 1-Could not find schema information for the element 'supportedRuntime
 & 2-Could not find schema information for the attribute 'version'.
 & 3-Could not find schema information for the attribute 'sku'.

Comment: delete section supportedRuntime, just in sample by default

Comment: and error: The specified store provider cannot be found in the configuration, or is not valid.

Comment: can you post your config file with string connection, in order to diagnostic

Comment: Can I get my data from SQLCE. But it can not send data!. There is no method Sutdents.AddObject(). please help me...